# Lost EVERYTHING in my Android app in Eclipse?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, xml-layout

I closed the main.xml Layout file in Eclipse, and all of the sudden, this is what I get:

[image]

**No XML content. Please add a root view or layout to your document**

All of the xml code is gone, the Graphic Layout editor is gone, and I can't get anything back. I lost the whole project. I'm in Eclipse 3.7.

I really need help with this. It has done this to EVERY Android project I've ever created. I can't finish an app. I get 2 activities done, then Eclipse bones me with this screen again.

Comment: This seems stupid .. but have seen the code . Sometimes UI part doesnt work properly.

Comment: Did you restart your Eclipse? Because, sometimes i'm also having this same problem.

Comment: Hi. Few Suggestions: 1.Please check if everything's intact in your workspace. 2. Clean your projects. 3. Update to newest version of ADT. See if all these help you and revert to this question thread. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be the xml dont save, you can try this:

right click the xml file -> compare with - > local history

in the local history to find right content